# Img Srcset Attribute Not Picking Smaller Image

Tags: html, srcset

The `<img>` element `srcset` attribute is consistently choosing the larger `<img>` `src`, even when the size media query is false.

Using a `<picture>` element to enforce image selection according to browser width worked well. I understand by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32285127/7933478) that `<picture>` and `<img>` `srcset` attributes work differently, `<picture>` elements can enforce image selection according to rules while `<img>` `srcset` yields choice to the browser's discretion. This can be according to screen pixel densities, network speed, or any other logic the browser employs. I've tried, in response, to force the browser's selection of the smaller image by disabling my Chrome browser's cache, shrinking my browser's width well short of the 800px media query (to about 300px to account for my retina display's 2x pixel density), and even throttling my own connection to that of a slow 3g network. Still, Chrome chose the larger 800px image.

Here's my `<img>` element so far...

```
<img 
    src="/image-2.jpeg" 
    srcset="/image-1.jpeg 800w, /image-2.jpeg 600w" 
    sizes="(min-width: 800px) 800px, 600px"
>
```

Consistently `/image-1.jpeg` is used as the `<img>` `src` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I can only see three possible reasons as to why the provided code isn't working;

(1). Browser support.
(2). File location or filename mismatch.
(3). Sizes of images specified in the code doesn't match the image size.

---

Use the following code snippet. This is working in Firefox for Desktop on Windows 10.

Confirm if the snippet below works for your browser when you resize the browser window. If it doesn't, then we have the culprit.

If it does work, then please check the following:

--> Filenames (typos)
--> File Extensions (.jpeg, .jpg, .png,...)
--> Image Locations (/image-1.jpeg)
--> Image Sizes (mismatched size) [It shouldn't really matter]

If everything is fine then maybe the browser doesn't have access to the folder containing the images. Check Permissions etc.

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=0"
 srcset="https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=0 800w,
         https://picsum.photos/700/350?image=1 700w,
         https://picsum.photos/600/300?image=2 600w,
         https://picsum.photos/500/250?image=3 500w,
         https://picsum.photos/400/200?image=4 400w,
         https://picsum.photos/300/150?image=5 300w,
         https://picsum.photos/200/100?image=6 200w,
         https://picsum.photos/150/75?image=7 150w,
         https://picsum.photos/100/50?image=8 100w"
 sizes="(min-width: 800px) 800px,
        (min-width: 700px) 700px,
        (min-width: 600px) 600px,
        (min-width: 500px) 500px,
        (min-width: 400px) 400px,
        (min-width: 300px) 300px,
        (min-width: 200px) 200px,
        (min-width: 150px) 150px,
        100px">
```

Run the code Snippet and resize the browser window.

Or, you can find this code in action on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yourpalnurav/pen/pGOOYE?editors=1100).

I hope this helps.

Peace

Comment: @D_N I can only see three possible reasons the provided code isn't working; (1). Browser support (2). File location or filename mismatch (3). Sizes of images specified in the code doesn't match the image size.

Comment: I've tried your snippet @YourPalNurav. On the latest version of Chrome (v72) the image does not change according viewport width. However, on the latest version of Safari (12.0.3) the image src does change according to viewport on reloads.

Comment: I've found that, if the sizes img attribute is abset, Chrome (v72) will pick from a srcset list detailed by width descriptors (800w, 600w) a src at least as wide as the viewport multiplied by the pixel density.

Comment: Dylan Landry     Did you get your problem sorted out??